# Using \emph and a subscript

Tags: subscripts, emphasis

How would I go about adding a subscript to a symbol I'm defining from an equation. 
For example I have an equation

`E_m = \alpha_m x + y`

How can I then do something like `\emph \alpha\textsubscript{m}`

The above gives me errors and I can't figure out how to correct this.

Comment: why don't you just set the substring as math?  i.e., `$\alpha_m$` -- `\emph` usually sets its argument in italic, and that's the usual math style.

Comment: Such a formula should be typed as `\(E_{m}=\alpha_{m}x+y\)`: TeX will take care of the details of math mode.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Do you want the subscript in italic, or roman? The usual `$E_{m} = \alpha_{m} x + y$` will give you italics, and `$E_m = \alpha_{\mathrm{m}} x + y$` will give you a roman subscript.

Answer (score 6):

Math formulas should be written in "math mode":

```
\(E_{m}=\alpha_{m}x+y\)
```

is the correct way to input that formula.

The ["Not so short introduction to LaTeX"](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=lshort&search_type=description) covers this topic and is available in many languages.